# node-sass: tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: sockets, npm, node-sass

This error shows up when I try to install node-sass. I need it to let work gulp protractor.

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testnew

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testnew>npm install node-sass
npm WARN package.json testproject@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json 2@0.0.1 No repository field.
-
> node-sass@2.1.1 install C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testnew\node_
modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up

> node-sass@2.1.1 postinstall C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testnew\n
ode_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
```

Does someone know how to fix this kind of error?